# App Engine CRUD with webapp - thoughts on structuring?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, crud

Two approaches:

```
# routes: (passed to WSGIApplication)
[..snip..]
('/note/add', AddNoteHandler),
('/note/delete/(.+)', DeleteNoteHandler),
('/note/view/(.+)', ViewNoteHandler),
('/note', ListNotesHandler),
[..snip..]
```

.. versus ..

```
('/note/(.*)', NoteHandler)

# which moves all the code from many RequestHandlers to one..
# ..but with a lot of branching inside, e.g.

class NoteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, params):
        params = params.split('/')
        action = params[0]
        id = params[1]
        # start switching by action

     def post(self, params):
        params.split('/'):
            # POST case
```

Having separate handlers for each CRUD operation on some `object` (in this case, `note`) will result in a lot more code being repeated in those handlers, and a humongous route list. On the other hand, I feel this would have a much cleaner, nicer structure that the one-handler-for-all-of-crud way of doing it.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Incidentally, "/note/(.+)/" for view, and "/note/(.+)/delete" for delete is more standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all of the handlers which share code subclass a base handler (which subclasses `webapp.RequestHander`).

That way you both have the routes and handlers separated properly and can factor out common code.